# Zend get db data in xml format using context switching

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am curious to know how can i get the database data in xml format in Zend framework using context switching.

Do i need to compulsorily specify the format in my url, like:

> http://localhost/pt/public/index.php/api/v1/users.xml?param1=3

I want to get the format from url (.xml, .json...) and apply the corresponding format to my  output automatically.

Currently iam doing this: I get the user data from the database. I get the users marks based on the class id i pass to the url:

```
$id = $request->getParam('param1'); // get class id param
$users = new Application_Model_DbTable_Users(); 
$result = $users->fetchData($id);

if(count($result) != 0)
        {
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->formatOutput = true;
            $root = $doc->createElement("Student");
            $doc->appendChild($root);



            foreach($result as $details)
            {
             $root_element = $doc->createElement("Marks");
             $root->appendChild($root_element);

             $TElement = $doc->createElement("Total");
             $TElement->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($details->marks));
             $root_element->appendChild($TElement);
                        }

                        $xml =  $doc->saveXML();
            $this->view->xml  = $xml;
                       }
```

And in the corresponding view script, i have this code:

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $this->xml;
?>
```

I get the user data and use DOMDocument to write the xml output to the view. But is it possible to automatically generate the XML data from database, without using DOM ?

Comment: A little bit similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542979/how-to-return-xml-in-an-zend-framework-application/

Comment: Thanks, but its using DOMDocument. I want to know how can i generate xml output with zend context switching, without specifying the content type explicitly, as i currently do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

emaillenin is right, there's nothing `ZF` can do to convert your data to XML.

But instead of forming `XML` manually (with `DOMDocument` and the like), I suggest that you take a look at [PEAR XML_Serializer package](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer/).

`XML_Serializer` allows you to transform arrays, objects, etc. to well-formed `XML`. You can also specify your root name, default tag names, indentation type, etc. So, you're pretty much in control for the resulting `XML`.

Comment: Thanks, i could pass my database output as array to the XML_Serializer and it is generating the xml output.

Answer (score 1):

Zend context switching helps in changing your headers, disabling layout and those kind of helps. It does not help in returning the database data as XML data.

The following code can be used to return XML output once you have converted your DB data into XML formatted data with tags.

```
class OutputController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function xmlAction()
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($sourceData);
        $output = $xml->saveXML();
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender(true);
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->disableLayout();
        header('Content-Type: text/xml');
 echo $output;

        exit();
    }
}
```

I will update the answer if you provide more information about how you retrieve the data from DB and what format of XML (the hierarchy of tags) you want in the output.

Comment: I added more info to my question, with the xml output generation code. I am explicitly specifying the content type as xml, but can i automate it with context switching?

Comment: I would like to know which system will be using this API? a mobile phone, a desktop software, or another web application etc?

Comment: This api will be used by another web application... it will send request to a resource and the response will be in xml format. Right now, i am using this xml serializer package: http://code.google.com/p/restful-zend-framework/source/browse/trunk/library/REST/Serializer/Adapter/Xml.php But i dont know how can i generate xml output for my scenario with this.

Comment: Basically I am using this approach... http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/233-Responding-to-Different-Content-Types-in-RESTful-ZF-Apps.html